# f is not increasing on any interval containing 0

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be the function defined by $f(x):= x +
x^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{x^4})$ for $x\ne 0$  and $f(0) := 0$. Show that f is differentiable and $f'(0) = 1$, but $f$ is not increasing on any open set containing $0$.

My work: $f$  is continuous at $0$ as for $x \in \mathbb R$, we have

$|f(x)-f(0)|= |f(x) \le |x|+|x|^2$. Now the function $g: x \rightarrow x^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{x^4})$ is differentiable at $0$ for $x \ne 0$, we have the inequality, $|\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}|=|\frac{g(x)}{x}| \le |x|$ proving that $g$ is differential at $0$ with derivative equal to zero at that points. As $f(x)=g(x)+x$, $f$ is differentiable at $0$ with $f'(0)=1$, $\forall x \ne 0$, we have $f'(x)=1-\frac{4\cos(\tfrac{1}{x^4})}{x^3}+2x\sin(\frac{1}{x^4})$. Did I miss anything? I am now stuck here to show that $f$ is not increasing on any open set containing $0$. I appreciate your kind help. Thank you so much!

Comment: If $U$ is open and contains $0$ then it contains points arbitrarily close to zero that have negative derivative (your formula shows this). $f$ is strictly decreasing at these points.

Comment: Am I done yet? Do I need to include any additional details?

Comment: If you add the contents of my comment that it looks good to me, but the level of detail required depends on your instructor.

Comment: Put a factor $4$ in the second term of $f'(x)$.

Comment: For $n\in \Bbb N$ and  $x=(2n\pi)^{-1/4}$ we have $f'(x)=1-4/x^3<0.$

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!